# Print a string in colors over a cold-warm color spectrum in Python

Tags: python, printing

I'm trying to create some character importance representation, as done in **Visualizing and Understanding Recurrent Networks** (https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02078).

Let's say I have a string (`s`) coupled with an array (`arr`):

```
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
arr = np.linspace(0, 1, len(s))
```

How can I print each character in the string (in color) according to some intensity taken from the corresponding index in the array (e.g., a to z characters are colored from cold to warm colors)?

For example (taken from the paper):

[image]

Comment: Do you know how you can print one character in one specific color?

Comment: Yes, so far, I played with variations of this code: 
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for c in s:
    print(f'\033[1;{ord(c) % 8 + 31}m{c}\033[0m', end='')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution by printing colors using RGB coordinates:

```
import numpy as np

def colored(r, g, b, text):
    return "\033[48;2;{};{};{}m{} \033[38;2;255;255;255m".format(r, g, b, text) 

def colored_print(text, grads, spectrum):
    _, bins = np.histogram(grads, bins=spectrum.shape[0] - 2)
    ranks = np.digitize(grads, bins)
    
    for c, i in zip(text, ranks):
        rgb = spectrum[i]
        print(colored(*rgb, c), end='')


temp = range(1, 255, 10)
cold = np.column_stack([temp, temp, len(temp) * [255]])
warm = np.column_stack([len(temp) * [255], temp[::-1], temp[::-1]])
spectrum = np.vstack((cold, warm))

s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
arr = np.linspace(0, 1, len(s))

colored_print(
    text=s,
    grads=arr, 
    spectrum=spectrum
)
```

printed output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why is the first char black?